# Qt questions and the C++ tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Should questions with the [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) tag be separated from the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tagged questions?

More often than not those question have very little or almost nothing to do with the C++ language. And the number of unanswered questions is growing. I think there should be some guidelines that discourage the use of C++ tag in such questions and maybe encourage the use of some more specific Qt-C++ tags instead.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from. While I see lots of qt specific questions sometimes these are though general c++ issues instead of Qt specific ones.

Comment: [qt] is a big enough tag that it doesn't need [c++].  Or [python].  Removing those tags is not going to do anything at all about reducing the number of unanswered questions.  About half of the [qt] questions gets an answer, that's a pretty good number today.

Comment: _"More often than not those question have very little or almost nothing to do with the c++ language."_ or vice versa.

Comment: They *are* separated: they have a [qt] tag. Use that to filter out the Qt questions when browsing C++ questions if you don't care about them. Don't try to bend the tag system to your own preferences, just use the filtering tools that already exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> More often than not those question have very little or almost nothing to do with the C++ language.

Yeah, and most JavaScript questions have nothing to do with JavaScript as a language. They're really about JQuery or browser's DOM or whatever.

Your request is really just a restatement of the oft-repeated argument for tags on the basis of purity. That is, wanting a pure C++/JavaScript/etc tag, which focuses specifically on language issues instead of having questions about libraries or implementations of that language (Qt/web browsers).

At the end of the day, separating Qt from C++ is no more of a practical reality than separating JavaScript from DOM. It's simply not going to happen; we have too many questions tagged that way, and people aren't going to listen to your tagging preferences. If people see a C++ tag and a Qt tag, and they have a question involving the use of Qt through C++, then that's how they're going to tag it.

If you want to find pure language C++ questions, you're just going to have to sift through them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> Should questions with the qt tag be separated from the c++ tagged questions?

They are already?

[qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) are already separate tags. If a question is only about QT and not related to C++, it should not have the C++ tag. Creating some strange merge tag "QT-C++" would make this impossible. Similarly, questions may of course be both about QT and C++.

- There are currently [31,467 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20qt) tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt).
- There are currently [30,139 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt%20-c%2b%2b) tagged [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) *and not C++*.

So it would seem to me that the separate tags currently work very well and you are making up a problem that doesn't exist.